# AttributeError for SUDS in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, suds

I am trying to include the SUDS library in a Python project through Google App Engine.

My code tries the following:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
```

And, once I've deployed on GAE, I encounter the following error:

```
File ".../myfile.py", line 13, in <module>
from suds.client import Client

File ".../suds/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
import client

File ".../suds/client.py", line 25, in <module>
import suds.metrics as metrics

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'suds'
```

I've been looking around for a little while, and it seems like SUDS is workable with GAE. I added the fixes outlined [here](http://omiethenull.blogspot.com/2010/08/suds-and-appengine.html), but that doesn't seem to be the problem. It seems like App Engine doesn't even get to that point.

Any info or suggestions?

I'm using Python 2.7 and SUDS 0.4.

Comment: I did figure it out eventually, though it's fallen far far out of my head by now. Apologies, hope you get your answer!

Comment: I did figure it out and shortly after that I realized GAE wasn't the platform to go forward with so now it's fallen far out of my head as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a simple `import suds.client`? Also make sure you include the suds folder in your application as App Engine doesn't include it by default. I hope that helps.